# Is "Erkennungsausweis" an actual word in German?

Tags: vocabulary

I found this word when ordering some lists with legal content (PDFs with translations from Italian to German), and failed to find it in my paper dictionary, so I tried the Duden online, but no results there either.

At this point, I directly tried looking up *"identity card"* in my digital dictionary and it says the translation is "Personalausweis".

Does "-r Erkennungsausweis" actually exist?

Comment: [Eine Frage für splattne `:-)`](http://dict.leo.org/Deutsch-Italienisch/Erkennungsausweis.html)

Comment: @HendrikVogt Ahah then I'll wait for him (if he's fast). :P

Comment: Scheint im Bauwesen verwendet zu werden...

Comment: @Em1 Could you translate, please?

Comment: @Alenanno I assume that this word is in use in construction engineering, but do not really know

Comment: ["In Baustellen statten die Arbeitgeber ihr Personal und die Selbständigen sich selbst mit einem **Erkennungsausweis** aus, der sichtbar getragen werden muss. Der **Erkennungsausweis** des Arbeitnehmers ist mit der  Lichtbild, persönlichen Daten, Namen des Arbeitgebers, Einstellungsdatum und im Falle von Weitervergaben auch mit der diesbezüglichen Genehmigung.  versehen. Der **Erkennungsausweis** des Selbstständigen, beinhaltet neben dem Lichtbild und den persönlichen Daten auch die Angaben des Auftraggebers"](http://www.provinz.bz.it/arbeit/service/113.asp?IFAQ_CATE_ID=8045)

Comment: This text says, that on construction site the employees are equipped with an *Erkennungsausweis* and they (employees) should take them visibly. Furthermore the text says what information are on the *Erkennungsausweis*.

Comment: @Em1 Thanks for the translation. :)

Comment: @Alenanno Maybe you can say us in which context you found this word. And maybe (if it was an article, page, ...) where it comes from

Comment: Same topic, other country, and this time in English: [Identity cards in the building and construction industry](http://www.arbeidstilsynet.no/fakta.html?tid=96288/#innledning)

Comment: @Em1 Edited. :)

Comment: @Alenanno Since you said it was a Italian original text, I am sure, that I am on a good way. I tried to phrase an answer.

Comment: @Em1: Schreibst Du auch Südhampton und Süd Karoline? ;)

Comment: @user: Interessante Frage! Laut Wikipedia ist [_Südkarolina_ oder _Südkarolinien_](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Carolina) im Deutschen veraltet - [_Nord-Dakota_](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Dakota) allerdings nicht. Ich stimme Wikipedia da voll zu. (Ein ähnlicher Fall: Ich spreche _Dublin_ englisch aus, _London_ aber deutsch.)

Comment: Gibt es einen Inhalt, der durch den Zusatz "Erkennungs-" transportiert wird, der nicht schon in "Ausweis" steckt?

Answer (score 14):

I'm from South Tyrol. The word seems to be a (IMO bad) translation of the Italian expression

> documento di riconoscimento ([Italian Wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documento_di_riconoscimento_in_Italia)) (the verb *riconoscere* means *erkennen*)

which means one of the following official documents:

- ID card (Personalausweis)
- driver's license (Führerschein)
- passport (Reisepass)
- etc.

in other words: an official any form of identity document that includes a photograph of the holder.

In my opinion the word

> (amtlicher) Lichtbildausweis

is the right translation for *documento di riconoscimento*.

Comment: So Personalausweis is indeed the best translation? :)

Comment: So the creation of the word *Erkennungsausweis* is: There was a wannabe translater, who was only able to translate word-by-word, but did not check if the outcome really exists!? What do you think @splattne? And @Alenanno, it still depends on context. *Personalausweis* can be the correct translation.

Comment: @Em1 I agree. This happens all the time here. Expressions from the Italian language get translated from people who shouldn't translate.

Comment: @Alenanno Maybe *Lichtbildausweis* would be the appropriate translation, because *Personalausweis* = carta d'identità; *documento di riconoscimento* means a superset of identity documents with photo.

Comment: Which one could match with "elektronischer ~" between Lichtbildausweis and Personalausweis?

Comment: @Alenanno it depends what is really *is*; a *Personalausweis* is a specific official document issued by the a (local) authority. Maybe *elektronischer Ausweis* would be better.

Comment: @splattne Could we say that "Personalausweis" = Documento d'identità, and "Erkennungsausweis" = Tessera di riconoscimento?

Comment: @Alenanno *tessera* is more a *card*, a *Ausweis* could also be a passport-like document. So, yes and no. :-)

Answer (score 10):

The origin of this word seems to be South Tyrol (Italy, Provincia Autonoma di Bolzano).
Regarding [splattne's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3670/1224), *Erkennungsausweis* is [just a mistranslation](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3661/is-erkennungsausweis-an-actual-word-in-german/3670#3670) for *documento di riconoscimento*. He also mentions the best translation is *Lichtbildausweis*, since it is a pass containing at least name and photo.

Most web links (written in German) refer to the building and construction industry, where everyone is obligated by law to wear an *identity card* on the building site so that it can be seen at all times. The mistranslation from Italian to German is the neologism *Erkennungsausweis*.

Since this is not a *regular* word in German, you won't find this word in [Duden](http://www.duden.de/) or any dictionary. At least as long as this word does not spread into regular German use.

[This page](http://www.arbeidstilsynet.no/fakta.html?tid=96288/#innledning) explains what this *identity card* is in the case of the building and construction industry. This page isn't from South Tyrol, but I did not find any better explanation in English.

More information (why, since when, ...) in German is [here](http://www.provinz.bz.it/lpa/285.asp?aktuelles_action=4&aktuelles_article_id=150290) (official site from South Tyrol).

Comment: Well said. An Internet search does demonstrate a somewhat extant use of the word but in the context and origin you've explained. To the question of whether the word is an actual word, this touches on German's generous ability to create new words by combining words together, which also makes it difficult to find them in a standard dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in German you could actually add all nouns together if you need to. So there could actually be an "Erkennungsausweis" somewhere out there. There actually could be a "Marmeladenausweis" (Jam card) somehwere. :)

But the translation for "identity card" is Personalausweis or short: "Perso"

Comment: That is just half true. 1) Of course you can join every existing words together, I think it is called neologism. But your example (*Marmeladenausweis*) does not make any sense as long as it isn't in use in food industry. 2) *Personalausweis* is one possible translation of *identity card*. Another possible translation is just *Ausweis*, so why not also *Erkennungsausweis*? When translating a word you always have to pay attention on context. And in this context, *Personalausweis* is utterly wrong.

Comment: 1) There are a lot of "Ausweise" out there. Every 2nd child magazine gives you a new "Agentenausweis" or something like that. So of course a "Marmeladenausweis" would make the most sense in the food industry.. or in some kind of Jam-Fan-Club... but it can make sense. 2) I've almost exclusivly saw the word "identity card" or short ID, in the context of a "Personalausweis".

Answer (score 1):

The German word "**Ausweis**" comes from "**(sich) ausweisen**", which translates to '**to officially identify yourself**' in English.

Therefore, since "Erkennung" means "recognition", it can be considered redundant. 
"Ausweis" is absolutely sufficient for describing general (official) identification.

Common variations of Ausweis are:

- "Personalausweis" => personal ID Card
- "Fahrausweis" => train or bus ticket
- "Presseausweis" => press ID card
- "Studentenausweis" => student ID card
- "Dienstausweis" => working place ID card, whereever one is needed, such as in police forces

Comment: Andererseits sind Verdopplungen im Sprachgebrauch nicht außergewöhnlich, etwa LED-Display.

Comment: @userunknown: LED steht für light emitting diode. Da gibt es keine Verdopplung.